# How to set folder permissions for a particular container on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have troubles setting permissions for a web folder on Elastic Beanstalk. I run multiple containers using custom docker images in one instance: apache-php, mysql, memcached, etc.. For the container "apache-php" I map a folder with my yii2 application to /var/www/html/.

When I manually make a bundle and do upload / deploy via Elastic Beanstalk console I sure have right permissions for the folder and everything works fine.

Now, when I deploy the app using "eb deploy", it drops all permissions and I get a server error and "The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/html/backend/web/assets" in logs.

I can connect via ssh and set necessary permissions manually, but sure this is not convenient, since needs to be done every time I re-deploy the app.

So, my questions is what is the best way to automatically set permission for particular folder in particular container on Elastic Beanstalk?

Perhaps, I can use .ebextensions, but I didn't find how to run "container_commands" for particular container.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## AWS EB Deployment starts your app in `/var/app/ondeck`

1. When deploying elastic beanstalk, your app is first unzipped into `/var/app/ondeck/`

   - Most likely, your local folder being deployed does not have the permissions you want on them.
2. If you need to make adjustments to your app, or the shell, during deployment, `.ebextensions/*.config` is the right place to do it.

## Container commands should be run to that path

But keep in mind, that these commands will run EVERY time you deploy, whether needed or not, unless you use some method to test for pre-config.

```
container_commands:
  08user_config:
    test: test ! -f  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.preconfig-complete
    command: |
      echo "jail-me" > /home/ec2-user/.userfile
  09writable_dirs:
    command: |
       chmod -R 770 /var/app/ondeck/backend/web/assets
       chmod -R 770 /var/app/ondeck/[path]
  99complete:
    command: |
      touch /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.preconfig-complete

files:
  "/etc/profile.d/myalias.sh":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      alias webroot='cd /var/www/html/backend/web; ls -al --color;'
      echo " ========== "
      echo " The whole point of Elastic Beanstalk is that you shouldn't need to SSH into the server. "
      echo " ========== "
```

Comment: Hi @Tony, could you please check how i can get error while I'm trying 

`commands:
  03_attachment_directory_permission:
    command:
      chmod 777 /var/app/ondeck/manellen/ticketing/attachments/`


and it return error `because:  (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)` in log file

Comment: @Manellen, you shouldn't use comments to ask questions. This question [has already been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357270/running-a-script-from-ebextensions-folder-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk), and typically is caused by attempting to access files on paths that do not yet exist. I.E.: `/home` doesn't exist yet when the app is deploying. The file created in this answer `/etc/ profile.d/myalias.sh` does not exist. Everything is being prepared in `/var/app/ondeck`.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas getting a `'/var/app/ondeck/my_app_folder': No such file or directory`

Comment: @TonyChiboucas could you provide offical docs link about deployment dir?

Comment: @e-cloud, I never found the official docs for it. AWS Documentation is a maze. Also, I'm no longer using elastic-beanstalk, so I'm not sure if it has changed since then. When in doubt, try it, and see what breaks.

Comment: just fyi i want to add here that im also getting nothing for "ondeck" - python env

Comment: I think EB may have changed the unzip folder from 'ondeck' to 'staging' - i.e. `/var/app/staging`, and then it moves staging across to the final name of '/var/app/current', so any changes made to staging persist after the move.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you should use ebextensions.

Create a folder in your app source root called `.ebextensions`. Create a file with a `.config` extension say `01-folder-permissions.config`. Files are processed in lexicographical order of their name.

Contents of the file can be:

```
container_commands:
    change_permissions:
        command: chmod 777 /var/www/some-folder
```

Replace with appropriate folder and permissions. Read about container commands [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands).

Comment: `/var/www` does not exist yet when container commands are ran.

Comment: chmod 777 is bad. Never 777. Nowhere. It's the hacker's jackpot.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas I have just came across this and need to change the permissions of a folder under /var/app/current but as you said, the folder does not exist, how do I go about executing the command once the files have been copied to the instance?

Comment: @BenOsborne, see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37199641/1589379) above. During deployment, the folders are in `/var/app/ondeck/`, and you can change the permission of them there. They are moved from there,  to `/var/app/current/` after deployment.