# Running a script from .ebextensions folder in aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run a script from when war is uploaded so here is the contents of configurations

```
container_commands:
    01_setup_apache:
        command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
    02_setup_script:
        command: "sudo su root"
    03_setup_script:
        command: "sudo mkdir -p /home/dev"
    04_setup_script:
        command: "sudo chmod 777 /home/dev -R"
    05_setup_script:
        command: "sudo cp .ebextensions/scripts/setup.sh /home/dev/"
    06_setup_script:
        command: "sudo chmod +x /home/dev/setup.sh"
    07_setup_script:
        command: "sudo /home/dev/setup.sh"
    08-restart-apache:
        command: "sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart"
```

I tried every thing but deployment always fail on executing setup.sh. In above example it fails on **07_setup_script**

Here is log contents

```
] : Starting activity...
/Command 01_setup_apache] : Starting activity...
/Command 01_setup_apache] : Completed activity.
/Command 02_setup_script] : Starting activity...
/Command 02_setup_script] : Completed activity.
/Command 03_setup_script] : Starting activity...
/Command 03_setup_script] : Completed activity.
/Command 04_setup_script] : Starting activity...
/Command 04_setup_script] : Completed activity.
/Command 05_setup_script] : Starting activity...
/Command 05_setup_script] : Completed activity.
/Command 06_setup_script] : Starting activity...
/Command 06_setup_script] : Completed activity.
/Command 07_setup_script] : Starting activity...
/Command 07_setup_script] : Activity execution failed, because: sudo: unable to execute /home/dev/setup.sh: No such file or directory
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

If **ssh** on instances there is no folder or file over there (/home/dev) or ( /home/dev/setup.sh) it seems previous commands were not executed but log says its completed

I know there is way to create a script file on run time, but can we avoid that and just use the above method.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of issues. You shouldn't start trying to manage a home directory/directory structure at all, that's definitely outside of beanstalk best-practices. Also don't run things as sudo, it executes hooks as root.

Do something like this:

in `.ebextension/foo.config`:

```
container_commands:
  01_restart_httpd:
    command: /etc/init.d/httpd restart

files:
   /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #content of your conf
```

or also

```
files:
   /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #content of your conf

  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/50_restart_httpd:
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: Yes that is what I am currently doing (run time file creation and appending the data), but I want my sh file to run.

Comment: Find where the post deploy files are in /opt and place one there, see example

Comment: The long story is dont start trying to create/manage a home directory, that's not "the beanstalk way". The proper way is a combination of the examples I posted in the answer.

Comment: I know we can achieve the same result as per your answer, but you haven't answered my questions, is it possible to execute your own sh file that is already created and present in .ebextension folder????

Comment: Yes it's possible but you need to add more troubleshooting. What are the contents of the script. Before you run #7 run another that does `ls -alh /home/dev/setup.sh`. run more commands before #7 to troubleshoot it's contents. My point was that you should not use sudo and there's no point to managing a temporary user, you're adding unnecessary complexity by avoiding best practices like I scaffolded for you.

Comment: That file contains a command to create a directory and set its permission, also if i copy all the contents and paste it in a way you have done, it works perfectly fine.