# Where do I create .ebextensions for it to work in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I need to create a few empty directories every time there is a new deployment.

I will follow the advice of the accepted answer in [How to set folder permissions for a particular container on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944651/how-to-set-folder-permissions-for-a-particular-container-on-elastic-beanstalk) and use the .ebextensions approach.

According to the documentation, I need to place this directory "in the root of your source bundle."
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Is this the root of the source bundle? /var/application/current

I followed the instructions and made a .config file and it is not being picked up or applied.

I have also tried manually creating the directories I need, but then in the web.stdout.log, my app does not have the permission to use the created directories. I even tried chmod 777 on these directories.

Please help me with creating these empty directories upon/after deployment

UPDATE:

I now zipped .ebextensions with my deployable jar, and i see in the logs that my .config is being picked up. However I am still facing the same permissions issue when I try to access the directory I am creating. What is wrong here?

createIODir.config:

```
commands:
  create_IO_dir:
    command: "mkdir /myIoDir"
    ignoreErrors: true
  create_input_dir:
    command: "mkdir /myIoDir/input"
    ignoreErrors: true
  create_output_dir:
    command: "mkdir /myIoDir/output"
    ignoreErrors: true
  create_record_dir:
    command: "mkdir /myIoDir/input/record"
    ignoreErrors: true
  create_schema_dir:
    command: "mkdir /myIoDir/input/schema"
    ignoreErrors: true
  create_json_dir:
    command: "mkdir /myIoDir/output/json"
    ignoreErrors: true
  create_avro_dir:
    command: "mkdir /myIoDir/output/avro"
    ignoreErrors: true
  permissions_IO_dir:
    command: "chmod 777 /myIoDir"
    ignoreErrors: true
  permissions_input_dir:
    command: "chmod 777 /myIoDir/input"
    ignoreErrors: true
  permissions_output_dir:
    command: "chmod 777 /myIoDir/output"
    ignoreErrors: true
  permissions_record_dir:
    command: "chmod 777 /myIoDir/input/record"
    ignoreErrors: true
  permissions_schema_dir:
    command: "chmod 777 /myIoDir/input/schema"
    ignoreErrors: true
  permissions_json_dir:
    command: "chmod 777 /myIoDir/output/json"
    ignoreErrors: true
  permissions_avro_dir:
    command: "chmod 777 /myIoDir/output/avro"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Comment: Can you show the folder structure of your deployment zip file?

Comment: @Marcin I just came across this 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html

I never did follow the zip approach but I can try that. Would this be acceptable:

project.zip
and inside this:
myApp.jar
.ebextensions

Comment: Yes. `.ebextensions` should be in the root (top) of your zip.

Comment: Ok, so I deployed the .zip file and I know that .ebextensions went through because I saw it in the logs. However I am still facing a permission denied issue when I try to access the directory I created in my .config file.

I will edit my question to include my .config

Comment: I would set `ignoreErrors: false` and actually check what are the errors. Also all sections in `commands` execute in alphabetical order. Thus normally you would do `10_create_IO_dir` and `20_create_input_dir` or similar, to enforce correct order. With your current setup its not clear if `create_IO_dir` executes before or after `create_input_dir` for instance?

Comment: @Marcin, done. and in the logs all the commands were executed successfully. Where have my directories been created? I cant find them in /var/app/current

Comment: You create them in the root (`/`) folder of linux. You have `/` at the beginning of each of your folder path.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, this is an accepted answer for me

Comment: nice. I will make answer then if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the commands.

The issue was that the folders were created in the **root** `/` of the linux file system, instead of in the deployment folder.

The **solution** was to fix the paths of folders created.